# .net desktop app installation

Tags: .net

I am creating a  C# .Net 4.0 desktop application for a client.  When I sent him the .msi files it requires administration privileges when trying to install.  I realize the reason why is because I am installing the application into the "Program Files" directory.

Is there a way to install an application into an area on the users machine that doesn't require them to install as Administrator?

I'm using .Net 4.0

Comment: see this http://serverfault.com/questions/19341/how-do-i-run-a-msi-installer-with-elevated-priviledges-on-windows

Comment: I guess I'm asking about when I'm building my project.  Can I build it so that the msi file doesn't need an admin to install it

Comment: Is there any reason that you like to use msi?  You can use the xcopy approach to do deployment.  Simply copy the whole folder to the place that the current user has permission.

Comment: He is in a different city.  So that is why I figured an .msi would work best.  I'm not familiar with xCopy are there any references about how to use it?

Comment: see the link in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether this will solve the "requires Administrator" problem, but you can change the target folder for your installation in "File System" view of your setup project:

- Right-click on the setup project in the solution explorer and choose View / File System.
- Select "Application Folder".
- In Properties, change the DefaultLocation.

Also it is usually a good idea to distribute setup.exe alongside *.msi, so any missing prerequisites may be installed automatically.

Comment: I did see that option.  I wasn't sure if that would solve my problem though.  I guess I can try it.

Comment: You might also try turning off the "InstallAllUsers" in Properties pane of your setup project (not the right-click Properties, you need to select the setup project and then switch to the "usual" Properties).

Answer (score 1):

depending on what dependencies the app has you could try an XCOPY deployment - although is seems that is only documented for VS2005 + VS2008...

We usually embed all dependencis into the app (in our case EXE-file), this way it can be "installed" by just copying it... as long as the framework needed (i.e. .NET4 in our case) is already there...

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235291%28VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you add the manifest file and assign to application then you need to set the Execution level.

Following is the line where you can set the Execution level.

<requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />

If you want your exe run always run as administator then you need to change the above statement as follow

<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />

See the following link how to create manifest file.

http://mahesg.wordpress.com/2007/07/30/adding-manifest-to-net-application/

Comment: This looked promising but in VS2010 I couldn't get it to work.  I get an error on one of the steps.

Answer (score 0):

I have got around the administration privileges by adding the "User's Application Data Folder" by right clicking on "File System on Target Machine" and moved all files from the "Application Folder" into it. The setup still prompts for the install directory but it is ignored. Shortcuts can still be setup as normal.

It installs to the following directory on Win7 C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming
Under xp it goes some where under documents and settings folder.

I asked the question why does google chrome not require permission and found that it installed to a slightly different folder C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application.